# wavesurfer.js does not draw waves in WordPress Firefox browser?

Tags: wordpress, wavesurfer.js

I create wave form player with wavesurfer.js. in HTML CSS it is work correctly in Firefox and Chrome but when I moved it to my WordPress theme in Firefox did not draw wave but is fine in chrome. do anyone have same issue?

JS file is loaded and music has played only not draw wave.

Answer (score 0):

You first checked the Script tag link loadded in your theme.
In the next step Check inspect firefox error log and attachment Url wordpress.

Comment: I check this js file and attachment file is loaded and music is played but not draw wave

Comment: please read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946223/wavesurfer-js-can-not-generate-graph-in-firefox-for-the-specific-mp3-audio-file