# 'The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type' Wavesurfer error in firefox

Tags: javascript, wavesurfer.js

This question is asked previously in the following link but didn't work for me.
[WaveSurfer JS can not generate graph in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946223/wavesurfer-js-can-not-generate-graph-in-firefox-for-the-specific-mp3-audio-file).

I used the following code to create an audio player by Wavesurfer JS.

```
 var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({ 
    container: '#waveform',
    backend: 'MediaElement',
    mediaType: 'audio',
    waveColor: '#f0f1f7',
    barWidth: 3,
    cursorColor: 'transparent',
    progressColor: '#ff4342',
    barGap: 4,
    responsive: true,
    height: 66
    });  

    wavesurfer.load('./assets/audio/test.mp3');
```

it works properly in all major browsers but when I install IDM ( internet download manager ) I encounter the following error in firefox and IDM tries to download the audio file and finally, the Wavesurfer graph isn't created. why this error occurs and how can I solve it?

The error code in the firefox console:

[error code in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raTyo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem is because my project is on the local computer and when I transfer it to a live server all errors are fixed and the audio player works properly.